# "Please wait" message for <h:CommandButton>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How to show "Please wait" message for `<h:commandButton>` ? . I knew how to show this modalPanel for `<a4j:____Button>`. 
 This request for an existing application which has close to 40 pages , out of 40, 10 of them implemented using `a4j:commandButton` and remaining `h:commandButton` . Adding common a4j:status in default layout (tiles) solve for all `a4j:commandbutton`.

Converting `<h:commandbutton>` to `<a4j:commandButton>` and add `<redirect>` would solve this issue, but is there any other way to accomplish this ? Any issues apart from increasing load ( two request for single submit) ?

Another Solution would be Adding

```
`onclick = "Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel')"`
```

in All `h:CommandButton` 
where `progressWaitModalPanel` is the modalPanel for "Please wait" - Any issues with this approach?

I would like to implement in one place and slight modification in each page if required, but not interested in refactor the entire application.

Thanks for your time.

 environment :
 
 Richfaces 3.1.6 , myfaces 1.1.7

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you: When a user clicks a `h:commandButton`, the "please wait" panel shall be shown.

You are right, on Ajax-Requests, the `a4j:status` component gets triggered and shows the mentioned message. I don't know any comparable mechanism for a normal/non-AJAX page-request (nothing more is a `h:commandButton` in the end).

Personally I would either go with your mentioned `onclick`-solution (lots of buttons to be changed, I guess) or would try playing around with something like

```
<h:form onsubmit="Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel')">
   ...
</form>
```

which might reduce the number of places to be changed.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your time. adding onclik/onsubmit doesnot show animation gif ( it is not animating due to the page got submit). But this one reduce the burden to change all the buttons